# Can I alter the biome of an area (without 3rd-party tools)?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

There's already a question on this (with the same exact title). However, there is one big issue: he is using 3rd party editor tool.

Is there any command to edit the biome? If not, can I give myself a grass block that has a texture of a certain command?

I cannot use a 3rd-party editor as I am admin on someone else's realm (and the are unactive)

I have seen maps with custom texture packs and believe I can replace the plains grass with another one (e.g taiga)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware, no. The biome information is now generated using the seed (since 1.2) and to change that without editing the nbt data is impossible. If you really want the biome changed, ask your friend to backup the world, download it, edit the nbt data, then upload that new world to the realm.

Comment: What about giving a block with a custom text pack (with the grass texture)? This sure is possible.0